# .NET Cast to Array Model Object

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a function which returns a List which just returns a list of emails and I want to cast it to my model for storage however I get this error:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'Linkofy.Models.Emails'.'

Is this because of the ID? can I just state a list in my model without creating an object for it? Thanks. I've not played with lists before but feel this would be the best way to store it? Could someone point out what is wrong here and if its not valuable to others I shall delete!

Casting code:

```
        List<string> emails = new List<string>();

        foreach (string url in urls)
        {
            getEmails(url);
            foreach (var item in getEmails(url))
            {
                if (emails.Contains(item))
                {
                    continue;
                }
                else
                {
                    emails.Add(item);
                }
            }
        }
        List<Emails> returnemails = emails.Cast<Emails>().ToList();
        return returnemails;
    }
```

My Model:

```
namespace Linkofy.Models
{
public class Outreach
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string domain { get; set; }

    public List<Emails> emails { get; set; }

    public int UserTableID { get; set; }
    public virtual UserTable UserTable { get; set; }
}
public class Emails
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Email1 { get; set; }
    public string Email2 { get; set; }
    public string Email3 { get; set; }
    public string Email4 { get; set; }
    public string Email5 { get; set; }
    public string Email6 { get; set; }
    public string Email7 { get; set; }
}
```

}

Comment: Your `emails` list type is wrong. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: @PatrickHofman what do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error says everything you need to know here.   There's no default cast for `string` to your `Models.Emails` type.

`Emails` is essentially an ID with a collection of e-mail addresses, it appears.  I would recommend using the .Net `System.Net.Mail` namespace instead of what you're doing here with strings, but in a lightweight application, strings are probably fine.

You will need to supply a constructor for your object, or change your `Emails` object properties.  I would strongly recommend the latter, or even doing both:

```
public class Emails
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string[] Addresses{ get;set; } 
    public Emails() {};
    public Emails(IEnumerable<string> list) 
    {
       this.Addresses = list.ToList().ToArray();
    }
```

and then in your code, each time you need a new EMails object, just construct one and add it to your list. Declare emails as a List instead of a List and bypass the need to cast:

`List<Emails> emails = new List<Emails>();`

and in your loops:
 `emails.Add(new Emails { emails = new string [] { item } });`

then you can access your emails by index.
My question is, though, why are you creating a listing object but only ever putting one entry in its email collection?

Comment: Fantastic answer thank you :) I see so the last 5 lines allow casting? In theory then could I could remove the list all together and store and array in my model? I'm not sure, so my reasoning behind this is I want to store multiple emails for one domain, I knew I could do this with an Icollection and another table but if I have thousands of domains I thought it may slow it down querying another table. So I was looking into alternatives but realised it was beyond me.

Comment: Your'e still better off with thousands of entries in an `IEnumerable()` or `Collection` than multiple declarations of variables that are all doing the same job.  Under the hood, they really come out to be arrays with sugar on top.  I wouldn't involve another table for what your'e doing; an object that is just an identifier and a collection of some sort will do the trick (including some collection types that involve their own identifiers).  Also, `System.Net.Mail` handles the domain issue in its objects, so look into that.

Comment: wonderful thanks for your help :)